# Lazy loaded module base template

Tags: javascript, angular

In app.module.ts I load 2 lazy modules like this

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: 'anonym', loadChildren: './anonym/anonym.module#AnonymModule' },
    { path: 'user', loadChildren: './user/user.module#UserModule', canActivate: [AuthGuard] }
];
```

In app.component.html I can write some base html. My question - is there any way to have base html for my UserModule?
I have tried to create user.component.ts and load it like in app.module.ts

```
import { UserComponent } from './user.component';
@NgModule({
    declarations: [UserComponent],
    bootstrap: [UserComponent]
});
```

but it's not show me user.component.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your user module define a base route with an empty path, and then define the sub-paths as children.

```
const ROUTES: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: UsersComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                pathMatch: 'full',
                redirectTo: 'login'
            }, {
                path: 'login',
                component: LoginComponent
            }, {
                path: 'logout',
                component: LogoutComponent
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

The `UsersComponent` will now be used as a base component, and if you navigate to just `/users` it will redirect to the `/users/login` path.

Make sure your `UsersComponent` has a template with `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` so the child routes.

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild(ROUTES)
    ],
    exports: [
        RouterModule
    ]
})
export class UsersModule {

}
```